# How to select a random element from a part of a list?

Tags: python, random

I have a list called `game`

```
game = ['X','O',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
```

I need to select a random element from all the `' '` elements only. It will then change it to X or O and do again.
Using simple `random.choice()` has a chance of never ending. `random.choices()` returns the element instead of its index so I cannot think of a way to update the weights.

Comment: Get the indexes of the elements that are blank or ' ' in a list and then do random.choice() on it. and then change corresponding data in your game list.

Comment: Rejection sampling with repeated calls of `random.choice` may be a reasonable thing to do here, the probability of it never ending rapidly approaches 0.

Comment: @miradulo rejection sampling is new to me and from what I read, I can't see a way to use it here. Can you explain it or give a link that explains it?

Comment: @KushagraGupta Just continue calling `random.choice` until you happen upon a `' '`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine which indices have spaces and use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to choose one

```
from random import choice

game = ['X','O',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
index = choice([i for i, x in enumerate(game) if x == ' '])
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. I can't believe I didn't even think of this.